# Glassfish: Spring boot error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, glassfish

I have a spring boot application deployed in Glassfish 5.0. When trying to access a REST service in this application with spring security basic auth, I'm getting the below error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SessionId.checkLength(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;)V

The application works fine in Tomcat server. This error is occurring only in glassfish server. 
My `JAVA_HOME` is already set to `jdk1.8.0_31`.
What could be the issue ?

Below is the error when I'm trying to access the service using postman:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

which means underlying jar lib in glass fish doesn't contain the class'smethod as springboot expected

Answer (score 0):

The jar file that contains the method `sun.security.ssl.SessionId.checkLength` may not be deployed in glass fish server. The package is expecting into the glass fish server. So find the package in which the `sun.security.ssl.SessionId` class is declared and and deploy the jar file of the package in the glass fish server. the package contains in your library list but the library is not deployed in glass fish server.

```
sun.security.ssl.SessionId  class is a part of jdk8. So make sure  your glassfish server using jdk8. it may not work in jdk7.
```

Comment: I'm not using this method `sun.security.ssl.SessionId.checkLength` in my application.

Comment: @M S Hossain I'm using `jdk1.8.0_31`

Comment: but some of interface or class is using this method. this class is a part of jdk8. So make sure your server is using jdk8. it may not work in jdk7

Comment: if your server using jdk8 then check where the sun.security.ssl.SessionId is being called. paste here the full error log.

Comment: check the java version of glassfish server. not in your local machine

Comment: Where can I find the jdk version in glassfish server ?

Comment: check your glassfish server version. and also check which version of jdk is using this version of glassfish server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152137/discussion-between-krishnanunni-p-v-and-m-s-hossain).